The difference between .gitignore and .Rbuildignore
I might be asking a dumb questions but can someone tell me the difference between .gitignore and .Rbuildignore when developing a R package with GitHub? Thanks.
EDIT: could you explain what kind of files to be included in either of these two files with examples?

.gitignore is used to prevents specified files from being tracked and included in version control.  That means this is used by git to ignore which files and directories.
.Rbuildignore:  is used by the R CMD build process to exclude files from the package tarball that is created when building the package.
